# JAXB marshals XML differently to OutputStream vs. StringWriter

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, java-metro-framework

I apologize if this has been answered, but the search terms I have been using (i.e. ***JAXB @XmlAttribute condensed*** or ***JAXB XML marshal to String different results***) aren't coming up with anything.

I am using JAXB to un/marshal objects annotated with `@XmlElement` and `@XmlAttribute` annotations. I have a formatter class which provides two methods -- one wraps the marshal method and accepts the object to marshal and an `OutputStream`, the other just accepts the object and returns the XML output as a String. Unfortunately, these methods do not provide the same output for the same objects. When marshaling to a file, simple object fields internally marked with `@XmlAttribute` are printed as:

```
<element value="VALUE"></element>
```

while when marshaling to a String, they are:

```
<element value="VALUE"/>
```

I would prefer the second format for both cases, but I am curious as to how to control the difference, and would settle for them being the same regardless. I even created one static marshaller that both methods use to eliminate different instance values. The formatting code follows:

```
/** Marker interface for classes which are listed in jaxb.index */
public interface Marshalable {}
```

---

```
/** Local exception class */
public class XMLMarshalException extends BaseException {}
```

---

```
/** Class which un/marshals objects to XML */
public class XmlFormatter {
    private static Marshaller marshaller = null;
    private static Unmarshaller unmarshaller = null;

    static {
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("path.to.package");
            marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");

            unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("There was a problem creating a JAXBContext object for formatting the object to XML.");
        }
    }

    public void marshal(Marshalable obj, OutputStream os) throws XMLMarshalException {
        try {
            marshaller.marshal(obj, os);
        } catch (JAXBException jaxbe) {
            throw new XMLMarshalException(jaxbe);
        }
    }

    public String marshalToString(Marshalable obj) throws XMLMarshalException {
        try {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            return marshaller.marshal(obj, sw);
        } catch (JAXBException jaxbe) {
            throw new XMLMarshalException(jaxbe);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
/** Example data */
@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Data {

    @XmlAttribute(name = value)
    private String internalString;
}
```

---

```
/** Example POJO */
@XmlType
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "project/schema")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Container implements Marshalable {

    @XmlElement(required = false, nillable = true)
    private int number;

    @XmlElement(required = false, nillable = true)
    private String word;

    @XmlElement(required = false, nillable = true)
    private Data data;
}
```

The result of calling `marshal(container, new FileOutputStream("output.xml"))` and `marshalToString(container)` are as follows:

**Output to file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>  
<ns2:container xmlns:ns2="project/schema">  
    <number>1</number>  
    <word>stackoverflow</word>  
    <data value="This is internal"></data>  
</ns2:container>
```

and

**Output to String**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>  
<ns2:container xmlns:ns2="project/schema">  
    <number>1</number>  
    <word>stackoverflow</word>  
    <data value="This is internal"/>  
</ns2:container>
```

Comment: Thank you for cleaning that up a bit, I had trouble not having the XML interpreted.

Comment: Further investigation has shown that what I am looking for is the ability to control whether JAXB writes "empty elements" in HTML (paired tags) or XML (single tag) style. In other JAXB providers like JaxMe, this is a property that can be set, but apparently not in JAXB. I just wonder why it is different depending on the destination type. I know they are functionally equivalent, but I need them to be identical to work with our system. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like this might be a "bug" in JAXB. Looking at the source, the calls for marshal() create different writers based on the output/writer type parameter:

```
public void marshal(Object obj, OutputStream out, NamespaceContext inscopeNamespace) throws JAXBException {
    write(obj, createWriter(out), new StAXPostInitAction(inscopeNamespace,serializer));
}

public void marshal(Object obj, XMLStreamWriter writer) throws JAXBException {
    write(obj, XMLStreamWriterOutput.create(writer,context), new StAXPostInitAction(writer,serializer));
}
```

The implementations of the writers is different with regards to how they handle "empty elements". The above code is from:

jaxb-ri\runtime\src\com\sun\xml\bind\v2\runtime\MarshallerImpl.java.

The two writers you are creating are:

jaxb-ri\runtime\src\com\sun\xml\bind\v2\runtime\output\UTF8XmlOutput.java

jaxb-ri\runtime\src\com\sun\xml\bind\v2\runtime\output\XMLStreamWriterOutput.java

Comment: More accurately this is a bug in the Metro JAXB implementation.  Other JAXB implementations such as EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) do not have this bug.

Answer (score 2):

The good news is that JAXB is a specification with more than one implementation (just like JPA).  If one implementation is not meeting your needs, others are available such as EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy):

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php

Comment: Indeed, as that link is now defunct

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why JAXB is doing this - or even if it is JAXB - if JAXB is outputting XML via a SAXContentHandler for example, then it has no direct control over how close tags are produced.

To get consistent behaviour, you could wrap your OutputStream in a OutputStreamWriter, e.g.

```
   public void marshal(Marshalable obj, OutputStream os) throws XMLMarshalException {
        try {
            marshaller.marshal(obj, new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (JAXBException jaxbe) {
            throw new XMLMarshalException(jaxbe);
        }
    }
```

Along the same lines, you might see what happens if you wrap the StringWriter in a PrintWriter. Maybe there is some custom code that detects `StringWriter` to tries to keep the output short as possible. Sounds unlikely, but I have no other explanation.

Comment: I ended up doing exactly this before checking back here and got consistent output. Thanks.